# Summation of convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Sum the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{2n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$
Is there some general method for summing such series?

Comment: Usually by inspection of the series. If you are able to get a pattern out of it.

Comment: For reference, WA indicates that the value is just $\log 4$. So this particular series shouldn't be too bad. But the more interesting question is to find some way to sum the terms $\dfrac{a}{an+1}-\dfrac{1}{n+1}$ with $a>1$.

Comment: If you write down the first several terms, it's $2(1-1/2 + 1/3- 1/4 + 1/5-1/6 + ....)$. Now try to find a pattern...

Comment: A general method using [$\psi$ and the polygamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) is provided in [$(6.8)$ of A&S](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_264.htm).

Comment: "Is there some general method for summing such series?" Do you feel the answer you just accepted provides a "general method for summing such series"?

Comment: In general, you could multiply the nth term with x^n, and then try to find a differential equation that the function satisfies. This will always work for so-called holonomic functions, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_function

Comment: I accepted the answer for the nice transformation to a known summable series. Actually I don't think that someone can provide method that always works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

\begin{equation}
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{2n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)
=
2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2n+1} - \frac{1}{2n+2}\right)
=
- 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{1}{n}
\end{equation}

So this is the alternating harmonic series, rest is up to you

Comment: While this certainly answers the particular (and rather straightforward) series posed in the question, this doesn't address the (much harder) bit about summing such series generically.

Comment: @Semiclassical, then the OP has to provide more information what kind of generalization he is looking for.

Answer (score -1):

We know $\frac12 \log \frac {1+x}{1-x}=x+\frac{x^3}3+\frac{ x^5}5+...$.

$\log ( {1-x})=-x-\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}3-..$.

So,$∑_{n=0}^∞(\frac2{2n+1}−\frac 1{n+1})=\log (1+x)$ at x=1 hence $\log 2$

Comment: I have edited now. Sorry typo.

Comment: yeah! I am surprised. Can anyone tell where is the actual problem arising. Rearrangement is possible for convergent series right??

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. However, I wanted to say that rearrangement is not possible for arbitrary convergent series- only for those which converge absolutely.